# react-native-meteor withTracker resubscribing repeatedly ever second unnecessarily

Tags: react-native, meteor

The below screen/component works fine, however the console.log statement (end the end of the file inside the withTracker section) repeats every second (forever) indicating the subscription is being rerun over and over for no reason - I know the data is not changing on the server/DB as I am the only user logged in to the app.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { Button } from "native-base";
import Meteor, { withTracker } from "react-native-meteor";
import moment from "moment";
import LoadingScreen from "../components/LoadingScreen";

class JobDetailsScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    posterInfo = this.props.navigation.state.params.posterInfo;
    this.state = {
      posterUsername: posterInfo.firstName + " " + posterInfo.surname.charAt(0),
      posterProfilePicUrl: posterInfo.profilePicUrl
    };
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props.myShiftRequestReady) {
      return <LoadingScreen />;
    }
    const job = this.props.job;
    return (
      <View>
        <H3>{job.type + ": $" + job.ratePerHour + "/hr"}</H3>
        <Image source={{uri: this.state.posterProfilePicUrl}}/>
        <Text>
          {this.state.posterUsername + moment(job.datePosted).fromNow()}
        </Text>
        <Text>{job.location}</Text>
        <Text>
          {moment(job.start).fromNow()
            + moment(job.end).from(moment(job.start), true)}
        </Text>
        <Text> {moment(job.start).format("DD/MM/YY h:mm a")
          + moment(job.end).format("DD/MM/YY h:mm a")} </Text>
        <Text>{job.summary}</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => {
            if (!this.props.myShiftRequest) {
              Meteor.call("ShiftRequests.add", job, (err, res) => {});
              return;
            }

            if (!this.props.myShiftRequest.accepted) {
              Meteor.call("ShiftRequests.remove", job._id, (err, res) => {});
            }
          }}
        >
          <Text>
            {!this.props.myShiftRequest
              ? "Request shift"
              : !this.props.myShiftRequest.accepted
                ? "Cancel Request"
                : this.props.myShiftRequest.didNotTurnUp
                  ? "You did not turn up for this shift"
                  : job.finshed
                    ? "Rate employer"
                    : "Shift in progress"}
          </Text>
        </Button>     
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const container = withTracker(params => {
  const jobId = params.navigation.state.params.jobId;
  const srHandle = Meteor.subscribe("myShiftRequestForJob", jobId);
  console.log("subscribing myShiftRequestForJob with jobId " + jobId);

  return {
    myShiftRequestReady: srHandle.ready(),
    myShiftRequest: Meteor.collection("shift_requests").findOne({
      userId: Meteor.userId(),
      jobId: jobId
    }),
    job: Meteor.collection("jobs").findOne({ _id: jobId })
  };
})(JobDetailsScreen);

export default container;
```

Comment: This code is way too long. Please provide an example that reproduces your issue with as few code as possible.

Comment: @Jankapunkt I have edited the code to remove all the visual static elements that should not have affected this issue, let me know if its more readable this way, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the subscription out of withTracker. in fact - I think the documentation example at https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-meteor is wrong in demonstrating this method because it can cause an infinite loop of subscriptions:

1. subscribed data changes, causing withTracker code to rerun
2. but inside withTracker, we are subscribing again! which causes the reactive values to change (potentially)
3. infinitely loop in the background, chewing up network and memory and CPU resources

The correct method is to subscribe to data in componentDidMount(), as suggested in this article: https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/

Modified code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import Meteor, { withTracker } from "react-native-meteor";
import LoadingScreen from "../components/LoadingScreen";

class JobDetailsScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    posterInfo = this.props.navigation.state.params.posterInfo;
    this.state = {
      posterUsername: posterInfo.firstName + " " + posterInfo.surname.charAt(0),
      posterProfilePicUrl: posterInfo.profilePicUrl
    };
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props.myShiftRequest || !this.props.job) {
      return <LoadingScreen />;
    }
    return (
      <View>
       ...
       <ComponentToDisplay/>
       ...
      </View>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const jobId = this.props.navigation.state.params.jobId;

    const srHandle = Meteor.subscribe("myShiftRequestForJob", jobId);
    __DEV__
      ? console.log("subscribing myShiftRequestForJob with jobId " + jobId)
      : null;
  }
}

const container = withTracker(params => {
  const jobId = params.navigation.state.params.jobId;

  return {
    myShiftRequest: Meteor.collection("shift_requests").findOne({
      userId: Meteor.userId(),
      jobId: jobId
    }),
    job: Meteor.collection("jobs").findOne({ _id: jobId })
  };
})(JobDetailsScreen);

container.navigationOptions = {
  title: "Shift details"
};

export default container;
```